# Swift Combine. What is a correct way to return from a block of a timeout handler?

Tags: swift, combine

I need to implement a handler for a timeout function in Combine. Let's consider the following code structure:

```swift
SomeKindOfPublisher<Bool, Never>()
   .timeout(timeoutInterval, scheduler: backgroundQueue,
      customError: { [weak self] () -> Never in
         ...
         while true {} // This block should not return because of Never
      }
```

My question is how to avoid a weird line `while true {}`? I would prefer not to change Never to Error type.

Comment: [`fatalError` "returns" `Never`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1538698-fatalerror)

Comment: @user28434, I do not want to stop the app by executing ```fatalError()```.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want, but the best way I found to handle timeout on publishers with no failure (`Failure == Never`) is to force a specific error type and handle timeout error in the completion.

```swift
enum SomeKindOfPublisherError: Error {
    case timeout
}

publisher
    .setFailureType(to: SomeKindOfPublisherError.self)
    .timeout(.seconds(1), scheduler: backgroundQueue, customError: { .timeout })
    .sink(receiveCompletion: {
        switch $0 {
        case .failure(let error):
            // error is SomeKindOfPublisherError.timeout if timeout error occurs
            print("failure: \(error)")
        case .finished:
            print("finished")
        }
    }, receiveValue: { print($0) })
```

If think it's strange that the timeout operator doesn't changes the publisher failure type to the custom error on its own, but this is some kind of workaround I found.